# How to fix sintax o procedure MySQL with variables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following body of procedure, that I can not save cause Mysql sintax error:

```
    BEGIN
    DECLARE v_user_id INT;
    DECLARE v_order_id INT;
    DECLARE v_min_price INT;

    UPDATE ordersperformers SET ordersperformers.Status = 1
    WHERE EXISTS (

    SELECT 
    MIN(ordersperformers.DeliveryPrice + ordersperformers.Price),    ordersperformers.Users_Id,
ordersperformers.Orders_Id
INTO v_min_price, v_user_id, v_order_id
   FROM ordersperformers 

    INNER JOIN
    orders ON orders.Id = ordersperformers.Orders_Id WHERE
    NOW() >= DATE_SUB(orders.DeliveryDate, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AND orders.Status = 0 AND ordersperformers.Status = 0
    ) AND ordersperformers.Orders_Id = v_order_id AND ordersperformers.Users_Id = v_user_id;

    END
```

It tells that problem near `INTO`:

[image]

Comment: If remove INTO, it comes work

Comment: Seems INTO does not work with INNER JOIN

Comment: Also I assume that `WHERE EXISTS` expects returned value, but therefore I set values to variables it returns something else not result

Comment: Perhaps replace WHERE EXIST ON `IF NOT NULL(Subquery)`?

Comment: Another assumption is variables are not available in sub query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading proposed solution, query can be simplified with `JOIN` clause and reduced `WHERE` condition:

```
UPDATE ordersperformers op 
INNER JOIN orders o ON op.Orders_Id = o.Id 

SET op.Status = 1

WHERE DATE_SUB(o.DeliveryDate, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) <= NOW() 
  AND o.Status = 0 AND op.Status = 0
```

Comment: Thanks I will test it, can you help me with this question, related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688249/table-specified-twice-in-procedure-how-to-fix

Answer (score 0):

I tested some ways, and have found working sintax, tha fixed my issue:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE v_user_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_order_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_min_price INT DEFAULT 0;

UPDATE ordersperformers SET ordersperformers.Status = 1
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 
MIN(ordersperformers.DeliveryPrice + ordersperformers.Price) = @v_min_price,    ordersperformers.Users_Id = @v_user_id,
ordersperformers.Orders_Id = @v_order_id
FROM ordersperformers 
INNER JOIN
orders ON orders.Id = ordersperformers.Orders_Id WHERE
NOW() >= DATE_SUB(orders.DeliveryDate, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AND orders.Status = 0 AND ordersperformers.Status = 0
) AND ordersperformers.Orders_Id = v_order_id AND ordersperformers.Users_Id = v_user_id;
END
```

Comment: This is a very weird query and sadly like many MySQL users you are not including non-aggregated columns in `SELECT` in the `GROUP BY` clause. Can you explain in words what you are trying to do? I only see the date filter and status columns as needed.