# Table specified twice in Procedure, how to fix?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got this message when attempted to run procedure:

[image]

**Procedure is:**

```
BEGIN

DECLARE v_user_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_order_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_min_price INT DEFAULT 0;

UPDATE `ordersperformers` SET `ordersperformers`.`Status` = 1

WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 
@v_min_price = MIN(`ordersperformers`.`DeliveryPrice` + `ordersperformers`.`Price`), @v_user_id = `ordersperformers`.`Users_Id` = @v_user_id,
@v_order_id =`ordersperformers`.`Orders_Id`

    FROM `ordersperformers`

INNER JOIN
`orders` ON `orders`.`Id` = `ordersperformers`.`Orders_Id` WHERE
NOW() <= DATE_SUB(`orders`.`DeliveryDate`, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AND `orders`.`Status` = 0 AND `ordersperformers`.`Status` = 0
) AND `ordersperformers`.`Orders_Id` = @v_order_id AND `ordersperformers`.`Users_Id` = @v_user_id;
END
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE ordersperformers op
    SET op.Status = 1    
WHERE op.Status = 0 AND
      op.Orders_Id = @v_order_id AND
      op.Users_Id = @v_user_id AND
      EXISTS (SELECT  1
              FROM orders o
              WHERE o.id = op.Orders_Id AND
                    NOW() <= DATE_SUB(o.DeliveryDate, INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AND
                    o.Status = 0 
             );
```

I changed/fixed a bunch of other things:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Backticks make the query harder to write and read.
- Conditions only on the table being updated should be in the outer `WHERE`, not the inner `WHERE`.
- Setting variables in an `EXISTS` subquery simply does not make sense.  `EXISTS` tests whether *rows* exist.  Logically, it could execute without ever evaluating the `SELECT`.

Comment: It is correct but does not update, from where do you get: `WHERE o.id = op.Orders_Id`?

Comment: I think this is redundant: `WHERE o.id = op.Orders_Id`

Comment: Are you sure about assigning value to variable `=@v_user_id`? Maybe `@v_user_id =  value`?

Comment: @OPV . . . Not at all, that is a correlation clause and it is what makes this work.

Comment: So, this query returns data: `SELECT * FROM orders  WHERE
NOW() <= DATE_SUB(`orders`.`DeliveryDate`, INTERVAL 2 HOUR);`

Comment: But your whole query return affected zero rows always

Comment: Where do you get value for `@v_order_id`?

Comment: And where did you lose `MIN()` because I need update only where min value for orderId and userId

Comment: @OPV . . . This fixes the problem that your query wouldn't run because the same table was specified in the `WHERE` and `UPDATE` clauses -- which is the question that you asked.  If you want correct logic, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.  I would not suggest editing this question, because you are likely to invalidate this answer, which in turn can draw downvotes.